# Is it sensible to go around Iceland in winter in a single week (Saturday to Saturday)?

Tags: driving, iceland, winter

After asking questions and reading some answers I'm starting to wonder.

Am I being a fool or just scaring myself?

Comment: Neither, just travel anxiety, both the good and the bad. Relax, have a carajillo, [read blogs such as this](http://youngadventuress.com/2013/11/iceland-road-trip.html) and have a great time on your trip.

Comment: You want to go around the Ring Road in one week ? Feasible but might be tight on time. Keep in mind a storm or road closure might delay your plan if you don't have a lot of time.

Comment: I'll guess I'll have to reschedule the trip and go sightseeing only the suthern part of the island instead of going all around it

Comment: ***No*** ***.***

Answer (score 1):

I travelled for 5 days in Iceland one winter (December) and managed to go in a day from Reykjavik to Hofn by hired car. Another time I drove to  Mivatan during May, so although I haven't completed a loop I've done most of it. The scenery is beautiful. The only thing you should consider you might be delayed due to road blockage (snow, ice) so when you plan your route, give a day or two days extra not to miss your flight from Reykjavik.